# Setting a hard limit for image size using PHP

Tags: php

I have this script for displaying a slideshow for a client.

I'm looking for a quick way of making the "**img**" not go over a certain size.

**This is my original code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#test2').crossSlide({
  speed: 15,
  fade: 1
}, [
<?php
$directory = "photos/";
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");
$arrLength = count($images);
foreach($images as $key=>$image){
echo("{src: '$image', dir: '$quotes[$random]'}");
if($key < $arrLength - 1){  echo ", "; }
}
?>
]);
});
</script>
```

Prehaps I could use some sort of external file?

Link it like.. image.php?img=foo.jpg (with the max script in there?)

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Comment: `#test2 img { max-width:400px; }` is also a pretty quick fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) is a start.

```
if( array_product(getimagesize($image)) < 2500 ) { // Check area
  // do stuff
}

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
if( $width < 500 && $height < 400 ) { // Check dimensions
    // do stuff
}
```

In the future, do a quick Google. PHP is a language that supports a lot out of the box. Often times, you'll be able to find something in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Provided that images are uploaded to the website, you should not allow images to be uploaded that are over a certain size of megabytes.

If you're talking about dimensions, you can use the `max-width:` and `max-height` CSS attributes to make sure images don't go over a certain size.

If you're looking to scale images (or anything else) proportionately, to fit the size of their container, you can use the JQuery [image resize plugin](http://ditio.net/2010/01/02/jquery-image-resize-plugin/) for that.